# How to make a part of texture emit light?

Tags: texturing, node-editor

I have made some lights here using a texture with dots and a transparent background. As you can see in the image, the switch to turn them on or off is the Fac value in the mix shader. This works just as I want, but now I also want to be able to switch the emission on from bottom up in an animation over time. How can I implement this?

Thanks in advance.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can get this:

[image]

by this node setup:

[image]

Just change the threshold to see the effect.

Blend file:
[image]

if you add one more math node...

[image]

you get:

[image]

my personal favorite: ;)

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can probably also clamp it somewhere to only light up whole dots (to mimic actual light bulbs turning on/off)

Comment: I am sure - but I like it more that way 

Comment: sure - different effects for different purposes :)